# why property binding in dynamic component creation not working?

Tags: qt, dynamic, binding, qml, components

signal 'clearPinFromDevManager(const QString& pinn)' will be emited repeatedly from cpp file. the signal caught onClearPinFromDevManager:{},so everything in cpp and main.qml files are ok, but 'recvClearPin' does not bind to PasswordWindow.qml component which is created dynamicly.

Note:If code has a problem, what is your solution to fix the problem?thanks

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import Terminal 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12


ApplicationWindow  {
id: rootId
visible: true
objectName: "window"
width: Screen.width
height: Screen.height
flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint

property var component
property var object
property string recvClearPin:""

Rectangle {
    id:rootRectId
    width: rootId.width
    height: rootId.height - headerId.height
    color: "#000033"
}

Terminal {
    id: terminalId

    onSignalToInitTerminal:{
         console.log("show Password window.")
            component= Qt.createComponent("Ui/PasswordWindow.qml");
            object=component.createObject(rootRectId,{clearPin: recvClearPin});
    }

 //signal will emit repeatedly
 onClearPinFromDevManager:{
        console.log("signal emited here and pinn is:",pinn)
        recvClearPin=pinn
    }
    
 }
}
```

PasswordWindow.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import "../Definitions.js" as Definitions


Item {
id:passwordWindowId
width: parent.width


    property string password: ""
property alias clearPin: textEditId.text

Text {
    id: passwordWindowTextId
    font.family: Definitions.LABEL_FONT_FAMILY; font.pointSize: Definitions.LABEL_POINT_SIZE
    text: qsTr("لطفا رمز خود را وارد نمایید")
    color: Definitions.LABEL_COLOR
    y: Definitions.PAGE_TITLE_Y_POS
    x: Definitions.PAGE_TITLE_X_POS
}

Rectangle {
    id: textEditRectId
    x: passwordWindowTextId.x +10
    y: passwordWindowTextId.y + height
    width: Definitions.TEXT_EDIT_WIDTH
    height: Definitions.TEXT_EDIT_HEIGHT
    border.width: 1
    border.color: "#000000"
    radius: 10
    color: Definitions.GENERAL_COLOR

    TextEdit {
        id: textEditId
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        text: ""
        font.family: Definitions.GENERAL_FONT_FAMILY; font.pointSize: Definitions.GENERAL_POINT_SIZE
        color: "blue"
        focus: true
        verticalAlignment: TextEdit.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: TextEdit.AlignHCenter

        onTextChanged: {
            console.log("texttttttttttttttttt:",text);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: what does your _does not bind_ mean? I see that type of the `recvClearPin` property is string. Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not bind the `clearPin` in this line: `object=component.createObject(rootRectId,{clearPin: recvClearPin});`. Instead you create a Json object with a item named 'clearPin' that has the current value of 'recvClearPin'. If you want a binding, use `Qt.binding`:

```
object=component.createObject(rootRectId,{clearPin: Qt.binding(function() { return recvClearPing} )});
```

Answer (score 0):

please provide more information where signal clearPinFromDevManager(const QString& pinn) is connected.

For dynamic objects you should use connect syntax in QML with cpp-objects.

You need register your class wich contains **clearPinFromDevManager(const QString& pinn)** in QML, then connect it to dynamically created object, or in onComleted-handler, like this:

1. Declare yous class in CPP/H:

   ```
   class CrearPinObject : public QObject {
      Q_OBJECT

      signals:
         void clearPinFromDevManager(const QString& pinn);
   }
   ```
2. Register it QML engine, main.cpp (or similar):

   ```
   ...

   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

   engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("CrearPinObjectView", new CrearPinObject);

   ...
   ```
3. Connect signal using QML-connect syntax (PasswordWindow.qml):

   ```
   Item {

      Component.onCompleted: {

        // CrearPinObjectView-object forward automatically
        CrearPinObjectView.clearPinFromDevManager.connect(clearPinFromDevManager);
      }

      function clearPinFromDevManager(pinn) {

         console.log(pinn);
      }
   }
   ```

Hope helped!